# ADC on STM32, Nucleo-F722ZE

Tags: adc, stm32, nucleo

I am trying to read ADC values on the Nucleo-F722ZE board.

- I have 3V from a power supply connected to pin PA3 on the Nucleo. Verified that the pin on the processor reads 3V.
- Grounds from the power supply and the Nucleo are connected.
- I checked the voltages on AVDD/VREF, they are correct at ~3.3V

However, when I read the ADC value, it shows up as ~600. 3V should give me ~3700. I have tried varying power supply voltage so that the voltage at the pin is 1V to 3V, however the values from the ADC remain constant at ~630.

I have tried the other two pins initialized in my code, PC0 and PC3, and they behave the same way.

I have a suspicion that the ADC is not configured properly. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

/* ADC1 init function */
void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 5;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;

  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
     _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

   /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_56CYCLES;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = 2;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_56CYCLES;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
  sConfig.Rank = 3;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_56CYCLES;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_VREFINT;
  sConfig.Rank = 4;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_56CYCLES;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_TEMPSENSOR;
  sConfig.Rank = 5;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_56CYCLES;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}

void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* adcHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 0 */
    /* ADC1 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC1_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0||GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* ADC1 DMA Init */
    /* ADC1 Init */
    hdma_adc1.Instance = DMA2_Stream0;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_0;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_adc1.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1) != HAL_OK)
    {
      _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(adcHandle,DMA_Handle,hdma_adc1);

    /* ADC1 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(ADC_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART3;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.Usart3ClockSelection = RCC_USART3CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

int main(void)
{  
  uint32_t ADC_Raw[5] = {0};

  HAL_Init(); 
  SystemClock_Config(); 
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init(); 
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init(); 
  MX_NVIC_Init();

  sprintf(buffer, "Nucleo Phase Shift\n");
  print((char *)buffer); 

  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)&ADC_Raw, sizeof(ADC_Raw)); 
  HAL_Delay(250);

  while (1)
  { 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I have not checked if all fields in local structs are initialized. It's good practice to explicitly initialize all local structs, e.g.

  ```
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {};
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {};
  ```
- Are the values from the internal channels, V<sub>REFINT</sub> and temperature, plausible? When yes, then ADC and DMA work, and GPIO setup is probably wrong.
- Are the GPIO and DMA clocks enabled? Can't find `__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE()`, `__HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE()`, or `__HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE()` in your code.
- This expression is wrong

  ```
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0||GPIO_PIN_3;
  ```

  there should be a single vertical bar `|`, meaning *bitwise* OR, instead of a double one `||`, which is a *logical* OR.
- Make sure that other peripherals that you are using, e.g. `TIM1`, don't take DMA2 Stream0 away from the ADC.

UPDATE:

**ADC channel numbers are all wrong.**

`PA3` is `ADC_CHANNEL_3`

`PC0` is `ADC_CHANNEL_10`

`PC3` is `ADC_CHANNEL_13`

You can get the channel numbers from the last column of Table 10 in the datasheet, or by just clicking on the pin in CubeMX.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response!  

    -The internal VREFINT and temperature values show up as 
     ~1490 and~ 930 respectively.  
    -Yes, the GPIO and DMA clocks are enabled.  
    -The logical OR (||) in place of the bitwise OR (|) was a typo 
      on my part.  
    -I tried running the code without initializing TIM1 and TIM3, 
     and still receive the same values on the ADC.

Comment: @notransients check the updated answer